# CSS - Label/Checkbox Image replacement

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:-

```
#profile-container ul label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    background: url(../img/c-unchecked.png);
}

#profile-container input:checked label:before {
    background: url(../img/c-checked.png);  
}
```

With the following markup:-

```
<ul class="acf-checkbox-list checkbox vertical">
    <li><label><input id="acf-field-interested_in" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="interested_in" value="permanent" checked="yes">Permanent</label></li>
    <li><label><input id="acf-field-interested_in-Temporary" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="interested_in" value="Temporary" checked="yes">Temporary</label></li>
    <li><label><input id="acf-field-interested_in-Interim" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="interested_in" value="Interim" checked="yes">Interim</label></li>
</ul>
```

I can't see why the image isn't being replaced once you click on the checkbox, any ideas?

Comment: You have to use javascript to dynamically toggle css states; your css rules as they are written are applied only over already outputed html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the nesting selectors:

```
#profile-container input:checked label:before {
```

`label` is not inside `input`. It's the parent of `input`, and sadly CSS has no parent selector. You can restructure your code to:

```
<li><input /><label></label></li>
```

Then use the sibling selector:

```
#profile-container input:checked+label:before {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from trying to target the parent selector `label:before` with `input:checked`. CSS doesn't allow you to 'climb up the DOM' in this manner. Instead you may want to try with the following markup :

```
<ul class="acf-checkbox-list checkbox vertical">
    <li><input id="acf-field-interested_in" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="interested_in" value="permanent" checked="yes"/><label>Permanent</label></li>
    <li><input id="acf-field-interested_in-Temporary" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="interested_in" value="Temporary" checked="yes"/><label>Temporary</label></li>
    <li><input id="acf-field-interested_in-Interim" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="interested_in" value="Interim" checked="yes"/><label>Interim</label></li>
</ul>
```

Don't forget to close your input tags as per the HTML specs!